# Insert Hyperlink in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In a WPF application I load news from an RSS feed. The contents are displayed in a TextBlock. This TextBlock has a certain size. Contents are cut off by the TextTrimming method.

Now I would like at the end of each TextBlock to insert a hyperlink button. The only problem is I do not know exactly what position will be cut on my string. Is there a way to figure this out?

When I insert my Text in my TextBlock and then my Hyperlink-Button, my HyperlinkButton will be cut of. Can I prevent to cut off my HyperlinkButton?

XAML-Code:

`<TextBlock Name="myText" />`

C#-Code:

```
Hyperlink hlink = new Hyperlink(new Run("here"));

myText.Inlines.Clear();
myText.Inlines.Add(value); //description from RSS Feed
myText.Inlines.Add(hlink);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add the HyperLink after the text, by replacing both items in a StackPanel?

Comment: The text is double spaced. Instead (...) of the TextTrimming-method should also this link button at the end of the text field.

Comment: That didn't make much sense. But obviously you can't insert a hyperlink between the ellipsis and the rest of the text. Instead you should trim the text, add the hyperlink, and manually add the ellipsis  if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your held. The difficulty now is figuring out how much text in my text box can be displayed, because each letter can vary in size.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirements this is one way to achieve your goals:

```
<StackPanel>  
    <DockPanel Width="200">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Text="A short description."  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">here</Hyperlink>   
        </TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Width="200">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="170" Text="A really long descripion of the item." />
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">here</Hyperlink>   
        </TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

So the [`DockPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) control might be a good candidate to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more convenient is to use a :

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Short description"/>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">here</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```